# C++ function binding at runtime with function name string in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, c++17

Suppose in the source code, I define a static function `void MyFun(void)`. Then I put a string `"void MyFun(void)"` in a configuration file. At runtime, I want to load the configuration file to get the string and then create/bind a function-pointer to the corresponding static function. Is it possible to do such a thing (I understand C++ doesn't have reflection)?

Comment: Are you looking for `std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>>`, `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()>>`?

Comment: You need to hard code the mapping for all functions you want to be able to find this way. There is no built-in way to find a function from a string.

Comment: @S.M. I am looking for a solution like:  std::bind(std::string, ....)

Comment: @Kenneth what do you mean by bind(string, ) and what do you expect?

Comment: @VolodymyrBoiko the string is the function's full assembly path and result is the function pointer. However, I realized unlike C#, this type of reflection is not supported by C++.

Answer (score 2):

Another option besides maintaining a map is to compile your code into a shared library and use OS API to lazy load symbols. This is ABI-depended solution though and in C++ you should be aware of name mangling or use extern "C" for function declaration.
The POSIX C example is taken from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Call_a_function_in_a_shared_library#C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
 
int main()
{
  void *mylib;
  int (*myfun)(const char *);
 
  mylib = dlopen("./mylib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  *(void **)(&myfun) = dlsym(mylib, "MyFun");

  /* ... */

  if (mylib) dlclose(mylib);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You can do this with Windows as well using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress - there is an example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/getprocaddress?view=msvc-160